# Twilio - how to maintain a conversation when responding to a call with a webhook

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

When I respond to a Twilio call with a webhook how do I wait for a response?

I'm using node.js. I can't seem to find it in the docs. Sorry if I missed it.

What I'm looking for is a short question/answer session. Respond with a question - then listen for the reply.

Comment: Are you after a response from the caller? By voice or dial tones? Have you checked out [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't wait for it.  It will post another response to your server when something happens.  It's the same as providing a document to a web browser and then waiting for the user to do something to go back to the server.  You can tie requests together by the CallSid.

Answer (score 0):

I should have spent more time reading. Indeed the `<Gather>` is the solution.

In Node.js you need something like this (using the SDK):

```
twiml.play({}, this.audio); 
if (this.outputSpeech) { 
    twiml.say(this.outputSpeech); 
}
twiml.gather({ 
    input: "speech", 
    timeout: 3, 
    method: "GET" 
});
```

There is [plenty more](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/06/how-to-use-twilio-speech-recognition.html) on the Twilio blogs.